# ProgressBar Overlapping at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, progress-bar, updating, overlapping

Hi i am new to android and i recently changed my theme to Holo ..but the progressbar seems to  overlap ..i.e a progress bar comes and stops ontop of which another continues to update the progress.. i even set the secondaryprogress to 0 also..but din work

Comment: You need to dismiss the progressbar once it completes

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..but there is no dismiss option for a progressbar..also i tried destroyDrawingCache(). but again of no use..

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883537/issue-with-android-layout-and-progressbar/5884128#5884128

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response..even im using async task for background purpose and displaying it on progressbar..but when i do it i first get a progressbar for for a half a centimeter and stops and then to be continued by another progressbar ontop of it to complete the progress with that progressbar present.. i could show the picture but its not letting me ..the image is like the one in this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106490/android-updating-view-in-realtime-overlapping-old-view